# (nautilus:13581): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gtk, gksu

Just installed gksu to use  `gksu nautilus`.

When running this command the output after entering password is

```
(nautilus:13581): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Not sure what caused this but i need to edit the usr folder.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Running `sudo nautilus` output was

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(nautilus:15545): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

This is running in Terminal not over SSH

Comment: Actually, before you install new things (mind you `synaptic` is highly recommendable), can you try something from terminal ? ....  (A) to open a Gnome terminal window, type in `CTRL+ALT+T` ; (B) type in `sudo nautilus` then enter your sudo-password - report whether nautilus opens or any error message. (C) still in terminal, type in `nautilus --version` and report on the version number you get for Gnome Nautilus.

Comment: BTW I run Trusty 14.04.3 LTS and I have no problem opening nautilus with `gksu`. No matter.  Since you are new here, to report, you can just _edit_ your own question: At the end of your original  question, write "EDIT: [whatever additional detail you want to add. Write precisely if you can.]". Tx

Comment: @Cbhihe Version output is: "GNOME nautilus 3.10.1"

Comment: Are you running over SSH or something?

Comment: @muru: Yes, the fact that XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not correctly set to `/run/user/[dddd]` has caught my attention too. It looks like the command is parsed on a different machine or at least in an environment different from that of the user emitting the command.  Somehow I doubt that SSH 's being used though. It seems we are missing something important.

Comment: @muru I am running directly off of Ubuntu Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I can easily duplicate your results by opening a terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> rather than <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> from within an Xwindows session. `nautilus` is a graphical application which must run under Xwindows. if you need a file manager to run in a terminal and aren't running Xwindows you might try using `mc` aka Midnight Commander.

If any part of this answer is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll add clarity as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Install Synaptic Package Manager.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Start the program. Search for Nautilus. You will see one of them isn't work correctly. Select for reinstall. Apply it.I had that problem too.

Comment: A couple nautilus packages needed to be upgraded but that didnt fix the problem.

Comment: Did you reinstall it or just upgrade? I suggest you to reinstall. If you get no chance after that just reinstall all nautilus. It must be work.

Comment: I'll look into that and see if anything helps.